# Spring Security + Thymeleaf - hide specific data from user if not authenticated

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I Think Thymeleaf doesn't know when user **is logged in** , I have hidden two `<a>` tags from users who are **authenticated** but they still are displayed.

> pom.xml :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

> Here's the code for problem - hidding two anchor tags from users
>   who are authenticated :

```
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
                xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4">
...
...

<div sec:authorize="isAnonymous()">
    <a th:href="@{/login}">Log in</a>
    <br>
    <a th:href="@{/register}">Register</a>
</div>

<br>

<a th:href="@{/recipeList}">List Page</a>
```

**Even after I log in , I still see the "login" and "register" tags**

> And here's the configuration, if its useful :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcUserDetailsManager jdbcUserDetailsManager() throws Exception{
        JdbcUserDetailsManager jdbcUserDetailsManager = new JdbcUserDetailsManager();
        jdbcUserDetailsManager.setDataSource(dataSource);
        return jdbcUserDetailsManager;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/register").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/recipeList").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/foodDescription/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/addNew/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN","USER")
                    .antMatchers("/delete/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .antMatchers("/edit/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                .logout()
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll();
        http.csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

My guess is that Thymeleaf doesn't know when user is logged in, if any other class is needed from my code, I'll edit it . Been stuck on this forever now.

Comment: Is your `pom.xml` is complete or did you skipped some parts of it before posting?

Comment: I skipped some parts of it

Comment: Don't ask two questions in one posted question. Post two separate questions. You already got a close vote for "too broad". However, if you search on SO you will find a lot of answer for your second problem. Try some of the solutions first.

Comment: Oh, sorry for that , I'll update my question and delete the second part :) @dur

Comment: Is your `User` class implements `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User` ? I am using exactly the same code as yours in many projects with some minor differences. I am using `formLogin().loginPage("/login")` as my login handler; if you have such a login page then set it and give it a try

Comment: Also please note your thymeleaf, spring-boot versions.

Comment: @Ahmet Yes indeed it implements userdetails.User class, maybe if I use custom login page it will work, I'll give it a try. As of thymeleaf and springboot versions, I think they are good cauz all the other code works fine :/

Comment: Nevertheless versions are important.

Comment: @Ahmet yes, the problem was in versions, u were correct :) Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are using Spring Boot 2.1.x

Then you have to use the version 5:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: It worked, god dammit I didn't even think about the correct versions ( I already thought it was the correct one that I had) . Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Welcome. I know because I made the same mistake :-)